# Trying to match Products and Requests through Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a rails marketplace app for uni where Users can be matched with specific products based on their request.

Users can list products that have specific categories.

Users can also list Requests where they can specify what products they're looking and their categories.

The aim is to match the request to a particular product based on the matching categories

Here are my models

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25}
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :request_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :request_categories
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class RequestCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I was thinking of creating a new model called Match to bring together the product and categories or is it easier to match it in the request?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here - is the Request sort of like a "wanted" ad?  And the goal is to match the user who posted the Request to products that match?  If so, is there a reason you wouldn't have both Products and Requests belong to a Category (rather than separate ProductCategory and RequestCategory classes)?

Comment: Sorry, reading it back it's a little bit unclear. Essentially I wanted to avoid buyers going through and searching listed items themselves and match them accordingly. Request is a crap name too. But as an example if I'm looking to buy a blue car used(category names), i would want all the listed products with those categories attached matched. Hopefully that's clearer. I'm new to this :)

Comment: Ah, and I misread it as well - hadn't noticed that ProductCategory and RequestCategory were just join tables for has_many :through associations.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, your new `Match` class would essentially be a join table for a `has_many :through` association.  Assuming that you're implementing an asynchronous worker (e.g. Sidekiq / ActiveJob) to go through and make "matches", you'll want to connect matches to a particular `Request`, and likely store some meta-data (has the user seen the `Match` yet?  Have they rejected it?)

So, I'd probably generate a `Match` class like this:

```
rails g model Match seen_at:datetime deleted_at:datetime request:references product:references
```

And set up the associations as follows:

```
class Match < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :product
end

class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :request_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :request_categories
  has_many :matches
  has_many :products, through: :matches
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
  has_many :matches
  has_many :requests, through: :matches
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Also, you'll likely want to add the `Request` has_many :through to your `Category` model (I think you forgot that one):

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
  has_many :request_categories
  has_many :requests, through: :request_categories
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25}
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

The big part of the job is working out how to have your app periodically look for matches - you may want to start with the [Active Job Basics](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) documentation.

Comment: Awesome!! I thought it was something like that. I'll definitely have a look at Active Job Basics. Much appreciated